# What happens if more than one user is updating an item?

Tags: list, updatelistitems, item

I've created a request portal in our SharePoint using custom list. There are several of us in the team who will have access to the list. What will happen if multiple users update an item in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when two or more users are simultaneously editing an item, if any one of the user save the changes then for other users on click of save button error message would be displayed

**Save Conflict. Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user. If you want your changes to be applied, click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and resubmit your changes.**

[image: Save Conflict]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm an absolute newbie who was assigned to be admin :)